# Not able to scroll list in non touch device in blackberry using phon2 gap technology

Tags: blackberry-webworks

I am not able to scroll list. I am using this code, please give me some suggestion.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Departure Schedule</title>
    <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/common.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/soapclient.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function GetDepartureStationDashboard()
        {      
             var pl = new SOAPClientParameters();
             var params = getParams();
             var parameter1 = unescape(params["getStationCode"]);
             var parameter2 = unescape(params["getStationDesc"]).replace(/[+]/g,"  ");
             document.getElementById("headingcontent").innerHTML = parameter2;
             pl.add("parameter1", parameter1);
             SOAPClient.invoke(WSDLURL, "GetDepartureStationDashboard", pl, true,  GetDepartureStationDashboard_callBack);
        }
        function GetDepartureStationDashboard_callBack(r)
        { 

// list which i want to scroll
            alert(r);// web service data
            var listdata = ""; 
            //tabledata += "<ul x-blackberry-focusable=\"true\">";
            //alert(""+r[0].stationName);
            for (var i = 0; i < r.length-1; i++)
            {
              //    
                listdata += "<li x-blackberry-focusable=\"true\"  id=\"i\"  x-blackberry-onUp=\"scroll(r.length-1)\" x-blackberry-onDown=\"scroll(r.length-1)\">" + r[i].stationName + "</li>";     
            }
            //listdata += "</ul>";
            alert(listdata);
            document.getElementById("iscroller").innerHTML = listdata;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="GetDepartureStationDashboard()">
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="login_cont" x-blackberry-focusable="true">
    <div class="home_icon"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/back-icon.png" alt="Home" title="Home" x-blackberry-focusable="true"/></a></div>
    <h1 class="fr">Departures</h1>
    <div class="cl"></div>
      <div class="mid_cont">
        <div class="grid_cont">
          <div class="heading_bar">
            <h1 class="fl" id="headingcontent"></h1>
            <input name="" type="button" class="heading_btn fr" value="Change" onclick="location.href='index.html'" x-blackberry-focusable="true"/>
            <div class="cl"></div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="30%">PLATFORM NO.</td><td width="30%">STD - ETD</td><td width="35%">Destination</td><td width="5%">STATUS</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="scroll-pane">

              <ul id = "iscroller" x-blackberry-focusable="true">
              </ul>

        </div>
        <div class="grid_error"><img src="images/help-icon.png" /> Departure Schedule</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="hdnStationName" id="hdnStationName" value="" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:

1. Make sure there are no run time errors happening. I don't see any `try-catch` statements in your code, so if any line of JavaScript fails, it could impact the entire application.
2. I see references to `iScroll`. That library is not guaranteed to work on BlackBerry (it was designed for another platform) especially on some devices as it conflicts with the BlackBerry web engine's natural kinetic scrolling.  If you do encounter an issue that you believe is rooted in iScroll, please [report it](http://cubiq.org/iscroll) to the developers.
3. If you are using BlackBerry 7, you can use remote web inspector to debug and profile live content. [This technique](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/web_inspector_overview_1553586_11.html) may help you find the root of the problems.